# Adding a Laravel Loop to avoid an "Unidentified Property" Error

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a bit of laravel code on my controller:

```
#Tickets
class PaymentsController extends Controller
{
public function store($event_token, Request $request)
{
if ($event_token != request('event-token')) {
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}

    $request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'required|min:2',
        'last_name' => 'required|min:2',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'event-token' => 'required',
        'bus' => 'required',
        'ticket' => 'required',
        'stripeToken' => 'required'
    ]);


    $event = Event::where('event_token', request('event-token'))->firstOrFail();
    $remainingTickets = $event->tickets - $event->sold_tickets;

    $bus = BusLine::where('origin', $request->bus)->get();
    $count = ( request('ticket')+0 >= 1 ) ? request('ticket')+0 : 1;
    $extra = 0;

    if ($remainingTickets < $request->ticket) {
        session()->flash('status', 'danger');
        session()->flash('message', 'OOOPS! It\'s seems that we are officially sold out. Sorry, se you next time!');
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }


    $price = ($event->price + $bus->price) * $count;
```

The line in the end gives this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$price
```

I saw other answers and I want to add the @foreach loop, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. I've tried a couple of ways, but they were all wrong.

Any help appreciated, thanks very much!

Comment: well its going to be either `$event->price` or `$bus->price` not existing as a property. Check if the property `isset()` before using it

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the output of `$bus = BusLine::where('origin', $request->bus)->get();` will always return a [Laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) (basically, an improved array). But you're calling `->price` on it, as if it was an object.

`->get()` will always return a collection of results from the SQL query. You can `foreach` over it as if it was an array (it implements [`iterable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) interface).

`->first()` for example (instead of `->get()`) will always return either an object or `null` (if no results are found).

Comment: If I use ->first() it gives the error "Trying to get property of a non-object", so that doesn't work. I just need to know how to use a foreach loop here, but I'm not sure how the syntax would go

Comment: It's impossible to know what you need for your use case. But the error you mentioned in the comment above happens because the query returns `null` (as no results are found), as I've mentioned in my answer.